# How to write groups for a delete comes under action menu odoo?

Tags: odoo

I need to write groups for a delete button under action menu in sale order form. This group is for to show if group is enabled then delete button will be shown or else it remains invisible.

I don't know how to make it. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by access rights. [Here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-remove-hide-the-delete-function-inside-the-more-button-by-role-group-131052) is elaborated example.

Suppose if you have to remove the delete option from the purchase order for the users purchase user, then what you have to do is that, activate developer mode, then go to the menu, Groups under the settings, then search the group purchase user. Open it, then in the access rights tab, you can see different objects and given permission.

Comment: Could you please help me to do it in backend for purchase module?

Comment: please elaborate ? Do you need help with the code?

Comment: I need to write access group for delete option under action menu for all forms in all modules. The requirement is, i need to enable group to let users could see delete button.

Comment: There are 2 ways to implement the same. If you have separate groups such as one for showing the delete and other for hiding then you can create different act windows and forms for respective groups and second solution is above one. But in order to implement above solution you have to consider the existing access writes.

Comment: Thanks @himanshu, I done it by using javascript.